# Efficient approach of working with XML Payload node in SQL server from C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, xpath, xquery

I working to find a match of a specific value from the C# code with the XML from SQL Server.

The data in SQL Server looks like this:

[image: DB Image]

Payload looks like below

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <MyTransaction>
      <Result>ResultValue</Result>
      <ToCompare>ToCompareValue</ToCompare>
  </MyTransaction>
```

Now, in C# code I have certain value for instance 'CSharpValueToCompare'.

For that, I need all the 'Result value' from the Payloads found in SQL Server

```
where ToCompareValue == CSharpValueToCompare
```

I am achieving this by using a stored procedure call which uses the cursor to open all the payloads and uses XPath query to compare the code and return the value if found.

Example code from stored procedure:

```
set @tPayloadXml = cast(@tPayload as Xml);
set @MyTransaction=@tPayloadXml.query('(MyTransaction/ToCompare  = "CSharpValueToCompare"])');
set @result= @MyTransaction.value(' (ns:Result/text())[1]', 'varchar(64)');
```

Using a cursor on this will be highly inefficient and that is not preferred and also too slow and dumb process.

I would like to achieve this using the best methodology.

Also, I have worked using the same in the c# code by using the entities context and to load all the desired payloads and search in them. But this approach is a lot more inefficient as compared to the previous one as I am loading all of them in the code and using 1 only if found.

Comment: So don't use a cursor. You can hoist the `.query` and `.value` calls into the query itself. Look into subqueries and `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: I am able to retrieve all the result value using CROSS apply but how can i introduce where on A.B .

SELECT 
 Result.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(64)') as ResultValue
FROM core.MessageTransactionVersion
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(Payload AS XML)) AS A(B) 
 CROSS APPLY A.B.nodes('MyTransaction/Result') AS MyTransaction(Result)
where CreatedBy = 'System'

Comment: I have achieved by making the variable table of column XML and used columnName.Value = 'XYZ' . Is this fine ? can we acheive this without making the XML column. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.value` to parse the xml directly in SQL.

eg:

```
declare @t table (payload xml)

insert @t (payload) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?><MyTransaction><Result>ResultValue</Result><ToCompare>ToCompareValue</ToCompare></MyTransaction>');

insert @t (payload) values ('<?xml version="1.0"?><MyTransaction><Result>ResultValue2</Result><ToCompare>CSharpValueToCompare</ToCompare></MyTransaction>');

select payload.value('(/MyTransaction/Result)[1]','varchar(64)') 
from @t
where payload.value('(/MyTransaction/ToCompare)[1]','varchar(64)')='CSharpValueToCompare'
```

Comment: Cant we do soemthing in C# code for the same ?  Like Iquerable queries of linq do.